# How can I submit a form without rendering it first?

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

What I would like to do is make a hidden form that I can submit using form.submit.  I can't use Ext.Ajax.request because I'm also uploading files.

What I have:

```
function uploadRequest(){
  var hiddenTextField = new Ext.form.TextField({
    id: 'hiddenTextField'
  });

  var gridForm = new Ext.FormPanel({
    id: 'hiddenForm',
    fileUpload: true,
    items: [hiddenTextField]
  });

  hiddenTextField.setValue('Test Value');

  var form = Ext.getCmp('hiddenForm').getForm();
  form.load(); // I want this to load hiddentextfield into the form?
  form.submit({
    url: '/main/grabValue',
    waitMsg: 'Uploading...'
  });
}
```

This works if instead of form.load() I add in:

```
var win = new Ext.Window({
  height: 450,
  width: 450,
  closable: true,
  items: [gridForm]
});

//I need something like a form.render that doesn't actually render here.
//hack that renders the form but also makes and shows a completely unnecessary form.
win.show();
```

How can I use form's built in submit functionality without rendering the form?

Comment: Render it off-screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just place it `top:-9999px;left:-9999px;` ? A lot of websites put hidden form fields in places like that to test for spam bots

Comment: Its better then my win.show(), but it still feels like a hack to me.

Comment: Out of curiosity may I ask why you need to submit a form specifically, and can't just emulate the actions a form submission takes (i.e., POST'ing data in PHP or etc.)?

Comment: I'm using the form as a hack to upload files.  I couldn't figure out how to do it with just a Ajax POST. Per this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978784/how-can-i-serialize-file-data-so-i-can-upload-it-to-my-server